# How do you show the decimal places from 0 to how many ever decimals in a float value?

Tags: c

Im working with C, and I am trying to print the values of pi in the format:
3
3.1
3.14
3.145
3.1459
etc.
But I am not sure how to do that any hints?

Comment: With `printf`, `"%.Nf"` prints `N` digits after the decimal point. So `"%.1f"` would be `3.1` and `"%.2f"` would be `3.14`, and so on.

Comment: I am trying to do printf("%.jf \n", pi); and it prints 3 repeatingly

Comment: It is not possible to format π as “3.145” since that is not a correct value for π.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <float.h>  //  For floating-point characteristics, notably DBL_DIG.
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    static const double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433;

    /*  Iterate through number of digits to display, up to number of decimal
        digits that double is guaranteed to preserve through round trip.
        (Note that DBL_DIG is the number of significant digits for that purpose,
        so DBL_DIG-1 is the number after the decimal point given that we have
        one digit, 3, before the decimal point.)
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < DBL_DIG; ++i)

        /*  Print with the number of digits specified in an argument.  An
            asterisk in a format field says to take the number that would be
            there from the parameters, and the number after "." in an "f"
            specification says how many digits to show after the decimal point.
        */
        printf("%.*f\n", i, pi);
}
```

Output:

```
3
3.1
3.14
3.142
3.1416
3.14159
3.141593
3.1415927
3.14159265
3.141592654
3.1415926536
3.14159265359
3.141592653590
3.1415926535898
3.14159265358979
```